# He made a grab for her bag. (succeeded to grab or tried but failed to grab?)

Tags: phrase-meaning

> He made a grab for her bag.

I think this sentence is vague: He grabbed her bag(succeeded), He grabbed for her bag(unsucceeded)

'make a grab for sth' means actually grabbed it or tried but failed?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's impossible to know whether the thief succeeded in stealing the person's bag or not. The sentence is too short, in any normal situation, the speaker would make this clear and add the *highly* relevant information.   Native speakers do not stop communicating after every utterance; they clarify, they expand, they repeat until their listener has understood.

Comment: @Mari-LouA You don't have to vote to close because 'make a grab for sth' means 'intended to grap sth'.

Comment: However, the question claims the sentence is ambiguous and vague. You're not sure if the thief stole the bag or not. I voted to close because the question lacked detail and effort.

Comment: I respect your opinion but my question is simple: make a grab for sth. There is a good answer below you can refer to.

Comment: That answer is the reason why I cast my vote to close the question. Read my reason and Michael's answer carefully. We're saying the same thing. ***It conveys nothing about success or failure***. *Further words would convey the result.* and *I’m voting to close this question* ***because it's impossible to know whether the thief succeeded in stealing the person's bag or not.***

Comment: @Mari-LouA You don't have to be resricted to A or B answer, since C could be an answer like two great answers here.

Comment: Two "great" answers? One upvote is not a reliable indicator of greatness. Each to their own :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To 'make a grab for' means *to try to take quickly*.

It conveys nothing about success or failure. Further words would convey the result.

He made a grab for her bag, succeeded in grasping it, and ran away

He made a grab for her bag, but she was too quick for him.

Answer (score 1):

To "*make a/an X for something*" means to do X in an attempt to do something else.

So, to make a grab for someone's bag means to make a grabbing motion in an attempt to steal it.

To "make a run for the border", for instance, means to run in an attempt to reach the border.